# Product structure of $H^*(\mathbb RP^{2n+1};\mathbb Z_2)$ using spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I am trying to compute the product structure of $H^*\left(\mathbb RP^{2n+1};\mathbb Z_2\right)$ using spectral sequence from $S^1\to\mathbb RP^{2n+1}\to\mathbb CP^n$, assuming that we already know $H^k\left(\mathbb RP^{2n+1};\mathbb Z_2\right)=\mathbb Z_2$ for $0\le k\le2n+1$.

We know that, for $q=0,1$,

$$E_2^{p,q}=H^p\left(\mathbb CP^n;H^q(S^1;\mathbb Z_2)\right)=H^p(\mathbb CP^n;\mathbb Z_2)= \begin{cases} \mathbb Z_2 & p \text{   even}\le 2n \\
                       0 & p\text{ odd,} \end{cases}$$

and $E^{p,q}_2=0$ when $q>1$.

Since we also know that $E^{p,q}_2$ converges to $H^*\left(\mathbb RP^{2n+1};\mathbb Z_2\right)$, we can deduce that all the boundary maps $d_2$ are zero map. Hence $E_2^{p,q}=E_{\infty}^{p,q}$.

In this case, let $\alpha\in H^0\left(\mathbb CP^n;H^1(S^1;\mathbb Z_2)\right)\cong H^1\left(\mathbb RP^{2n+1};\mathbb Z_2\right)=\mathbb Z_2$ be the generator. If we use the $E_2^{**}$-product structure, we should get

$$\alpha^2\in H^0\left(\mathbb CP^n;H^2(S^1;\mathbb Z_2)\right)=0.$$

However, this is a wrong answer since $\alpha^2$ should be a (nonzero) generator of $H^2\left(\mathbb RP^{2n+1};\mathbb Z_2\right)$. I think that I probably have some misunderstanding on the product structure of Leray spectral sequence. Can anyone point me out the mistake?

Comment: I didn't read it all but there's a good chance you made no mistake. I think there are extension problems involved in inferring the ring structure of the thing you're trying to compute.

Comment: $\alpha^2$ need not be a generator. Groups $E^{0,*}_\infty$ are quotients of $H^*(E)$.

Comment: The issue is simply that there is an algebra extension problem that must be solved in moving from the graded group $E_\infty$, to which the sequence abuts, to the cohomology module $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^{2n+1};\mathbb{Z}_2)$. To solve it you need information about the Bockstein $Sq^1$, which acts as the squaring operator on any degree one class.

Comment: If you know Poincaré duality and the cohomology ring of $\mathbb{C}P^n$, then this spectral sequence has given you enough information to deduce the cohomology ring of $\mathbb{R}P^{2n+1}$.  I am happy to add details if you'd like.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I would love to know more details, thanks.

Comment: @Y.H.Chan.  Upon beginning to write up a answer, I realized that my methods don't compute $\alpha^2$ like I thought.  Sorry!